# display one image on top of other image inside <li>

Tags: html, css

So, for fun I'm building an iOS homescreen. I'm displaying the icons using `<ul>` and `<li>`.
The li's are build like this:

```
<li><img/><img/></li>
```

The first image is a delete button with `display:none`, the second image is the actual icon. If you long click the second image, the first one fades in. However, I do not know how to display the first image in the top right corner of the second image using css. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you done so far? can let us look by providing a Fiddle from jsfiddle.net

Comment: @rockStar http://jsfiddle.net/uqbS7/

Comment: do it really need to be a `ul` ? coz u can do that too using `div(s)` and display them `inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of ways you can do that. Assuming the icon takes up the full space of the li, you could do this:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li img:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but then it shows the delete button on the top right of the page...

Comment: An element which is positioned absolute will be relative to either the <body> or the nearest parent element with position: relative. Sounds like you need to make the parent relative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be pure css you need these two to be positioned absolutely `position:absolute;`. Then make the 'x' button image the same size as the icon image. Then just give those two images the same `left` and `top` value.

```
#first_mage_id, #second_image_id {position:absolute; left:X; top:Y;}
```

Remember to replace X and Y with some values (depending on where you wish it to be). If it doesn't work show us your code so we can help you.